# What kind of variable should I use?

Tags: templates, variables, meteor

I am using Meteor and have an opinion question.

I have a series of templates that I designed for making interactive tables: sortable column headers, pagination, reactive counter of table's elements, etc. Up until now I have been storing several pieces of information (current page, items per page, and sort order) as session variables so that it was easy to access them from every template regardless of their relationship (parent, sibling...) to eachother.

This has worked alright until now, but now I want multiple tables on the same page. Since I have statically-named session variables, information gets overwritten by other tables on the page.

I am working on a bunch of solutions and welcome other suggestions. What do you guys think?

1) Name every table and store all the information for every table on the site in a giant session variable, which would be an object keyed by tables' names. The downside here is that every table would need a unique name and I'd have to keep track of that. The upside is that implementing the table in new parts of the system could be easier than ever. Also, table sort/filter/page information would be stored even when leaving pages (but could be overridden if that were desired).

2) On the template that contains all the table parts, define reactive variables, then explicitly pass those down to lower levels with helpers. This would help with our goal of cleansing the system of session variables floating around (not that all session variables are bad), but would be a trickier refactor and harder to implement new tables with. Information would not be remembered when navigating between pages.

3) Each table template could reference the parent's reactive variables (messy, but possible) and look for specifically named ones (such as "table_current_page"). This would make setup of new tables easier than #2, but would only allow one table per template (but multiple per page would still be possible).

None of these are quite ideal, but I am leaning towards #1 or something like it. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please check the [help/on-topic], asking for opinions is explicitly off-topic. Your question is about comparing 3 different approaches to a problem, which is unfortunately also very broad. People will have their own ways of approaching this issue and answers / votes will be based on opinions rather than facts (_"I feel like this is cleaner..."_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other user commented on your question, opinion based questions are off-topic on SO. But anyway here is my opinion,

Option 1: I would not use this! This way, even if one of the reactive parameters for one table changes all other tables helpers will re-run and those tables will also re-render. As your application grows and probably when it is time to have more than 4-5 tables at a time, you might feel the performance is not that good.

Option 2: I will definitely use this, this (as you mentioned) is very cleaner way. No performance impact (like the one mentioned in option 1), even if you have multiple tables in the same page.

Option 3: If you do this you will have very strong dependency between those templates. So all child templates cannot be used independently elsewhere.

So if you have enough time then go for option 2. If not, option 1 with a slight change, that is, instead of one large session variable, you can use multiple smaller session variables that have a unique table name as prefix or suffix. This does pollute your `Session` variables but it will not have performance impact.

*This is my opinion.*

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had not thought of the reactivity re-render issue. I might lean towards multiple session variables because passing reactive variables around gets very messy and isn't really what they were designed for. (I know this is was opinion question, but unfortunately this is the best site for advice regardless, and you were very helpful!)

Comment: @AutumnLeonard yeah, I agree with you, this is the best website to ask such questions.